# How do I format a piece of text so it prints on new line after max line length. Please assist

Tags: word-wrap

For instance, suppose that the response you want to output is: “I am sorry, I have no
information on that. Could you be more specific?”
If the maximum length has been set to 20, then the response might be output as follows:
01234567890123456789
I am sorry, I have no
information on that.
Could you be more
specific?
(Note that the line of numbers is just provided to help you see the line length and should
not be part of the actual output.)

Comment: What language are you coding in?

Comment: I'm using Java language.

Answer (score 0):

```
int mySplit = myString.lastIndexOf(' ', 20);
```

This will return the position of the last space (if any) before character 20.
Take the string before that position as your output line and replace the contents of the string with everything after that position.

```
myOutput = myString.substring (0, mySplit-1);
myString = myString.substring (mySplit+1);
```

Repeat until myString <= 20 and then add it to the output.

I'm no Java expert and there may be a more comprehensive method in a library somewhere but that will work.

Tidying up and fixing the code from your comment below:

```
public void wrapString(String myString) 
{ 
    String myOutput = ""; 
    int mySplit = 0;

    while (myString.length() > 20)  // Keep going until we still have to split it
    {
        mySplit = myString.lastIndexOf(' ', 20); 
        myOutput = myString.substring (0, mySplit-1);  // Take this out FIRST
        myString = myString.substring (mySplit+1);     // THEN consider the rest
        System.out.print(myOutput);                    // Show the part we found
    }
    System.out.print(myString);             // Now show the rest
}
```

Comment: I've just tried to implement this in code but I think I may have gone about it the wrong way as it is not printing out anything. I must add, I am very new to Java. Never done programming before.

so far, what I have is this:

`
public void wrapString(String myString) {
        String myOutput = "";
        int mySplit = myString.lastIndexOf(' ', 20);

        while (myString.length() <= 20){
            myString = myString.substring (mySplit+1);
            myOutput = myString.substring (0, mySplit-1);
        }
        
        System.out.print(myOutput);
    }
`

Comment: I've tidied up your code in the answer. Bear in mind that if you have a word longer than 20 characters, mySplit will not contain a valid value and you will need to decide what to do. (You may have to tweak it - I don't have a java system installed).